# Externally trigger dag which has schedule_interval=None

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a controller dag named **dss_controller**

```
dag = DAG(
dag_id='dss_controller',
default_args={
    "owner": "dss admin",
    "start_date": datetime.utcnow(),
},
schedule_interval=None,
)
```

and a target dag named **dss_trigger_target_dag**

```
dag = DAG(
dag_id='dss_trigger_target_dag',
default_args=args,
schedule_interval=None,
)
```

Tasks are defined in both controller and target dags as in the default available examples.

This system works as expected when **dss_controller**'s *schedule_interval* is set to "**@once**".

Then I have set it to **None** and triggered externally. It'll trigger the controller dag and move it to the **running** state and then move it to **success** state.

But it won't trigger **dss_trigger_dagrun** task of the controller dag. 
What's reason for this behavior?

Setting **schedule_interval**=None was the reason, if so how?

This my controller dag,

```
import pprint
import pprint
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
   """This function decides whether or not to Trigger the remote DAG"""
   c_p = context['params']['condition_param']
   print("Controller DAG : conditionally_trigger = {}".format(c_p))
   if context['params']['condition_param']:
      dag_run_obj.payload = {'message': context['params']['message']}
      pp.pprint(dag_run_obj.payload)
      return dag_run_obj

   # Define the DAG
   dag = DAG(
      dag_id='dss_controller',
    default_args={
        "owner": "dss admin",
        "start_date": datetime.utcnow(),
    },
    schedule_interval=None,
)

# Define the single task in this controller example DAG
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='dss_trigger_dagrun',
    trigger_dag_id="dss_trigger_target_dag",
    python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
    params={'condition_param': True, 'message': 'Hello Hasitha'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

and this is my target dag,

```
import pprint
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

args = {
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'owner': 'dss admin',
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dss_trigger_target_dag',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
)


def run_this_func(ds, **kwargs):
    print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".
          format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='target_run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have added "start_date" as now() in the default arguments, that go to each of the tasks. It seems, that is the real culprit. Airflow recommends against it since it can prevent triggering tasks ever.
Try setting the start date to something in the past, such as airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1).

---

Refer: https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date

Comment: Yes- if you want to limit to external triggers, you are correct in setting `schedule_interval=None` but you must include a valid `start_date` . It can be set with `days_ago` or similar, as suggested, or it can be any arbitrary date. There's a PR to make `start_date` optional for the external trigger use case, but for now this is the right workaround as far as I know.